# Finding strings' "permutation" based on alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, permutation

I would like to ask for advice, if there is a more efficient way to find a strings' permutation based on its alphabetical order, like my code below. 
I'm working with strings long up to 16 characters, and huge amount of data, and running my program takes too much time and memory.

Basic representation of the problem

input:  alphabet

output: 16752348

So in the word "alphabet" letter 'a' is the first in the alphabet, mark it index 1, then comes another 'a' in the fifth position, mark it 2, then comes 'b' in the sixth position, mark it 3 and so on..

In the code I don't use numbers as indexes, instead of, I use characters, so from value 65 of the ASCII value. (Because I use test long strings. But it doesn't change the main purpose). So the output of my program will be

input:  alphabet

output: AFGEBCDH

```
public static String perm(String word){

    char[] perm = new char[word.length()];
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    char[] sortedWord = new char[word.length()];

    sortedWord = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(sortedWord);

    for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<word.length(); j++){

            if (sortedWord[i] == wordArray[j]){
                perm[j] = (char)(65+i);  //from A
                wordArray[j] = '.';

                j = word.length();    //in case, if the word has more of the tested char, we jump to the end of the cycle
            }
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(perm);
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println(perm("alphabet"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at my previous solution, and it appears Arrays.sort() for an array of comparable takes considerably longer than on arrays of primitive types.
I tried a couple more approaches, and the following is the one that gave smaller time for large number of words:

```
  public static String perm(String word){
    int l = word.length();
    int[] els = new int[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
      els[i] = (word.charAt(i) << 16) | i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(els);
    char[] sb = new char[l];
    for (int i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
      sb[i] = (char)('A' + els[i] & 0xFFFF);
    }
    return String.valueOf(sb);
  }
```

Note that the approach makes the implicit assumptions that the words only use the lower 15 bits of the UTF-16 encoding (true for words in english alphabet).

In terms of memory utilization, you have to be a bit careful about what you measure in Java. The fact that memory utilization may spike in one approach vs. another, is not necessarily a good indicator, as that memory may be garbage collected. All of the approaches here use temporary arrays/objects which are available to garbage collection after perm() is executed (except for the returned string). Now, if you care about reducing memory utilization in order to reduce garbage collection (and therefore improve performance), I suspect this last approach should give good results, although I haven't measured that.

Comment: This was the fastest method, although I need to do it for local language too. For that I made a lookup table with the coresponding alphabet of the language.

Answer (score 0):

WRT memory utilization, the program you pasted won't use much. What are you doing with the returned strings in the real code?

As far as performance goes, this should be a bit better:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class El implements Comparable<El>{
 char c;
 int idx;

 public El(char c, int idx) {
  this.c = c;
  this.idx = idx;
 }

 public int compareTo(El other) {
   return Character.compare(c, other.c);
 }
}

public class Perm {
  public static String perm(String word){
    int l = word.length();
    El[] els = new El[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
      els[i] = new El(word.charAt(i), i);
    }
    Arrays.sort(els);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(l);
    for (int i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
      sb.append((char)('A' + els[i].idx));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println(perm("alphabet"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The returned string I put in a hashMap, and counting, that how many words are mapped to concrete permutations.

Comment: I tried your version, and sadly in all my tests it used more memory and took more time to finish program as mine. The longer the word is, the slower your method is. 
For example strings by length = 10 chars, my method runs 4 sec, and your 14 sec. (tested 10 million words)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class alphabet {
    public static List<CharIndexHolder> charlist = new ArrayList<CharIndexHolder>();

    public static String perm(String word) {
        char[] perm = new char[word.length()];
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
        char[] sortedWord = new char[word.length()];

        sortedWord = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sortedWord);

        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j<word.length(); j++){

                if (sortedWord[i] == wordArray[j]){
                    perm[j] = (char)(65+i);  //from A
                    wordArray[j] = '.';

                    j = word.length();    //in case, if the word has more of the tested char, we jump to the end of the cycle
                }
            }
        }   
        return String.valueOf(perm);
    }

    public static String perm2(String word) {
        charlist.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            charlist.add(new CharIndexHolder(word.charAt(i), i));
        }
        Collections.sort(charlist);
        for(int i = 0; i < charlist.size(); i++) {
            charlist.get(i).assignedindex = i;
        }
        char[] result = new char[word.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            CharIndexHolder cur = charlist.get(i);
            result[cur.index] =(char) (charlist.get(i).assignedindex + 65);
        }
        return new String(result);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println(perm("alphabet"));
        System.out.println(perm2("alphabet"));
    }
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class CharIndexHolder implements Comparable<CharIndexHolder> {
    public int index;
    private char character;
    public int assignedindex;

    CharIndexHolder(Character character, int index) {
        this.character = character;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CharIndexHolder o) {
        if(this.character < o.character) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(this.character > o.character) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(this.index < o.index) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(this.index > o.index) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }       
}
```

I can't think of a way to go faster than N*log(n).  If you need more speed, try replacing the list with a long array, but only allocate the array once per batch (not once per call).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. I tried you method as well, but the result is similar to Roberto's. in all my tests it used more memory and took more time to finish program as mine. The longer the word is, the slower your method is. For example strings by length = 12 chars, my method runs 9,7 sec, and your 41 sec. Roberto's method 38 sec. (tested 10 million words)

Comment: Can you post your test code that you used to measure execution time?

Comment: I just use 
`long start = System.nanoTime();` before my cycle and write it after it ends
`System.out.println("Duration: " + ((System.nanoTime()- start)/(Math.pow(10, 9)) ) + " sec" + System.lineSeparator());`

Comment: How are you generating the strings?  Or are you using the same string everytime?

Comment: Sorry for misinformation, I forgot few lines for my method when measuring.
Your method = 30 sec
My method = 26 sec.

I use always same Strings. Reading from a file

Comment: Sometimes a O(n^2) algorithm can run faster than n*log(n) as long as n is small enough.  Your solution involves allocating 2 new arrays on every call and that is a cost that I was trying to avoid.  However, maybe pushing elements onto an array, even if the same array is re-used every time, involves more CPU cycles, perhaps through function calls.  How long is your list of strings and are all your strings the same length?